# Are there calcium channel blocking neurotoxins?

Tags: neurophysiology

I am learning about calcium ion channel blockers (CCBs) and am confused whether there are neurotoxins that are CCBs.

1. If they exist, what is an example of a CCB neurotoxin?
2. What animals use CCB neurotoxins as a weapon / defense tool?

Comment: This seems like it would be easy to Google. Have you tried?

Comment: I did. Several times. I found plenty on sodium. Potassium was easy too. But not CCBs. If you find it, paste the link in bio chat and I can delete this.

Comment: Just to clarify, they can be toxic, but it's not clear to me if they are a neurotoxin used by animals in the same way that, for example, tetrodotoxin is.

Comment: First hit: http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v372/n6503/abs/372272a0.html

Comment: But they are cone snails. Is that OK?

Comment: Yes, my professor mentioned those, although I do not think that she necessarily specified that cone snails contained calcium blockers. Thanks! I can find a bunch of info now

Comment: That was so helpful! Thanks again. In future, should I post this sort of "I cant find blah blah" in chat?

Comment: You can do that, sure. That's probably a pretty good place to do that. :)